# Is it possible to set literal handling mode for specific clause in Hibernate?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

Since Hibernate 5.2.12 it's possible via spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.criteria.literal_handling_mode to set INLINE handling mode for all expressions. It occurs, that it's problematic, because of NPE if there's enum as literal expression.

My motivation here is to get rid of problem with many bind parameters to in clause (the postgres limit is reached very easily). Unfortunately the project is generically based on criteria API predicates - so there's no way to rewrite programatically the collection to where clause as sql string.